# c++ - how to convert char to int?

Tags: char, int, printf

I try to write a function who convert a string to an integer (like atoi). I don't  see why my function "convertir" don't print my variable "res " whereas "test 1 " "test 2"... "test 4" is printed. I let you look at my code and if you see something bad tell me please.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int xpown(int x, int n); // x^n
int lent(char str[]); // return length of string
int convertir(char s[]); //convert char to int
int main(){
    char s[] ="1234";
    convertir(s);
    return 0;
}

int xpown(int x, int n){
    int res = 1;
    while (n != 1){
        res= res*x;
        n--;
    }
    return res;
}

int lent(char str[]){
    int res =0;
    int i=0;
    while (str[i] != '\0'){
        res=res+1;
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}

int convertir(char s[]){
    int res = 0;
    int i = lent(s);
    int j = 0;
    char c = s[j];
    while (c != '\0'){
        c=s[j];
        printf("test %d \n", j);
        res = res + (c - 48) * xpown(10,i);
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    printf("%d", res);
}
```

Comment: You can't use `#` for comments in C++. Those should be `//`.

Comment: For simplicity, you can use `c - '0'` instead of `c - 48` to get a digit, as `0` is a `char` with ASCII code 48. This way, your code becomes a bit more readable.

Comment: I didn't know it thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `i` too high. Consider the simplest case, where `s` has 1 digit. You want to multiply that digit by `1` (10<sup>0</sup>), not `10` (10<sup>1</sup>). So it should be:

```
int i = lent(s) - 1;
```

BTW, you shouldn't hard code the value `48`, use '0':

```
res += (c - '0') * xpown(10, i);
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard function atoi() will likely do what you want.

Comment: I want to rewrite atoi because I study C, and i think it's a good exercice

Comment: He says he's trying to write a function like `atoi`. So obviously he's interested in learning how to do it himself.